# Word counter code skips

Tags: c, arrays

I tried to write a code that will look for a specific word inside a string and that will count it's place within the string . 
If the word doesn't exist inside the string, it should print that the word wasn't found.
For example, for the sentence "I am late" , for "late" the result should be 3.

```
int count=0,i=0,j=0,k;
char word[30];
getchar();
gets(word);
k=strlen(word);
while(arr[i]!='\0'){
    if(arr[i]==word[j]){
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    i++;  
    if(arr[i]==' ') // moves across a word in the string
        count++;    // count a word the index has passed
}
if(j==k)            // if all letters were a match
    printf("The word %s is placed in the %d place." , word , count);
else
    printf("The word %s is not found." , word);
}
```

The problem is that for every sentence entered, it prints:

> The word %s is not found.

I assumed that it skips for some reason the first part, and goes straight into `word is not found`, but even after debugging I couldn't catch the moment and  reason why it skips.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [DO NOT use `gets()`, it is dangerous](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2173917). use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.

Comment: Your code seems to be testing if the letters in `word` appear in the letters in `arr` -- but not necessarily contiguously. That isn't what you want, so you have a fundamental logic error in addition to whatever other bugs are in your code. Your code seems to be missing an inner loop. Alternatively, you could use `strtok()` to split on space and compare the strings returned from `strtok()` with the target word using `strcmp()`. Also --heed the warning of @SouravGhosh .

Comment: step through with a debugger

Answer (score 1):

Note that `i++` appears twice in the main loop, once conditionally and once unconditionally. The fact that it appears twice means that when a matching letter is found, `i` is incremented *twice*. The intention behind your code could be realized by getting rid of the conditional `i++`. Making this change and getting rid of the `getchar()` (which seems pointless from my point of view since it just discards the first letter of the input) and replacing `gets` by a not-quite-perfect use of `fgets` yields (with removed lines commented out):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    int count=0,i=0,j=0,k;
    char * arr = "I am late";
    char word[30];
    //getchar();
    fgets(word,30,stdin);
    strtok(word,"\n"); //trick for stripping off newline of nonempty line
    k=strlen(word);
    while(arr[i]!='\0'){
        if(arr[i]==word[j]){
           //i++;
           j++;
        }
        i++;  
        if(arr[i]==' ') // moves across a word in the string
            count++;    // count a word the index has passed
    }

    if(j==k)            // if all letters were a match
        printf("The word %s is placed in the %d place." , word , count);
    else
        printf("The word %s is not found." , word);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it and enter `late` I get the result:

```
The word late is placed in the 2 place.
```

Which seems to be almost what you want (there is an off-by-one error if you wanted the number 3). But, don't celebrate too soon since if you run it again with the input `mate` you get:

```
The word mate is placed in the 2 place.
```

Your code (once fixed this way) is really testing if the letters of the input word appear in order in `arr`, but doesn't check if the letters appear next to each other. You need to rethink your approach.

Comment: Also, when the two letters don't match, the OP should be setting j back to 0 to avoid the second issue you brought up about looking for the letters in order and not contiguously.

Comment: eventually i got the result i desired, after adding a condition that word[j]!=EOF. thank for your answer